# Does BitBucket / GitLab has graph of Contributions or Activity, just like GitHub?

Tags: github, bitbucket, gitlab

I am recently trying GitLab, it's working good, feels more like BitBucket.

Does anyone know that, in `BitBucket` or `Gitlab`, is it possible to have the Graph of contributions / activity, like `GitHub` ? I like this feature.

Comment: I haven't seen it on GitLab, but I don't know about on BitBucket

Comment: I think you can find it in GitLab, just noticed it. Bitbucket doesnt have it yet.

Comment: Sorry I thought you are talking about project contribution graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it was introduced in 7.10 I think. You can see it on your profile page.